# Goland doesnt recognize module

Tags: go, goland

I'm having issues with Goland recognizing my imports.

So, with a basic sample structure like this

```
 - main.go
 - go.mod
 - folder/something.go
```

imports from `folder` arent recognized.

E.g. below import, within `main.go` isn't valid, and Goland complains with the message `Cannot resolve directory somename`

```
import "somename/folder"
```

The go.mod was initialized with `go mod init somename`

Why is this happening? Why Goland can't resolve somename to the module that I created?

Comment: Please try `go vet` and post the error.

Comment: What is the package declaration inside `folder/something.go`? Also please try and report if the `go` tool can compile your module (IDEs might have unrelated, configuration errors). Also what's the version of go you're using?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi go vet doesnt output anything
@icza package decl in `folder/something.go` is `folder`
btw. go compiles this without issues, Goland just doesn't recognize the imports

Comment: @eja Then maybe your Goland does not know you golang installation path or smth like this? You could look for a tutorial on how to setup Goland.

Comment: It's possible Goland doesn't use module mode. Check its configuration. Also do check your Go version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer: [JetBrains GoLand Docs: Working with Go modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/create-a-project-with-go-modules-integration.html#working-with-go-modules)

In GoLand's docs, it is mentioned that if you haven't created the Go project from the IDE itself then you have to configure it to use Go modules manually.

> If you create a new Go modules project in the IDE, Go modules are already enabled. If you pulled your Go modules project from Github, you need to enable Go modules manually.

So, I assume that's why you are facing the problem. But you can follow the docs and configure your IDE correctly.

Answer (score 7):

If the IDE is unable to recognize your internal packages then:

1. Inside Settings find `Go Modules`
2. Enable the `Enable Go modules integration` checkbox.

Comment: thanks so much for this!! I wonder what it is and why not just enalbed by default...

Comment: Had done "invalidate cache & restart" before writing any more codes.